# Can I put field bounds on a template type in Rust?

Tags: rust, yew

In rust I can put trait bounds on a template argument to guarantee it conforms to the functionality I want:

```
fn print<T:Debug>(t: T) {
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

Can I do something similar with fields?

```
fn print_name<T:HasNameField>(t: T) {
    println!("{:?}", t.name);
}
```

I'm not trying access a specific field (for which I could make some accessor trait). I am trying to promise a 3P function that I have certain fields, similar to how we promise functionality in a template w/Trait bounds.

My use case is that in yew I would like to create a form. Instead of just using `<input type="text".../>` I would like users to be able to create their own input fields and be able to build CustomForm. And then I could have:

```
#[function_component(CustomForm)]
fn custom_form<T: yew::Component>() -> Html {
    <form>
        <T name="field name"/>
    </form>
}
```

Currently this fails with the following message:

```
error[E0609]: no field `name` on type `<T as yew::Component>::Properties`
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust `1.62.0 (2022-06-30)`, traits cannot require fields.
Though, you can use a function instead.

```rs
trait Named {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}
```

Then, just implement it as you would any other trait.

```rs
struct NameImpl;

impl Named for NameImpl {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        "my field name"
    }
}
```

You can use it as a type bound, and call `get_name()` as you please.

```rs
fn do_stuff_with_named<N: Named>(n: N) {
    println!("{}", n.get_name())
}
```

Comment: Though in a situation like this, if you are writing the trait as well, you may simply want `do_stuff_with_named` to be _in_ the `Named` trait.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the call site. I am using the `yew` library. Otherwise I would have done the solution pointed to here. I think I really need a way for the call site to know that `name` is a field of T.